# Issues with Web source module POST request Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I am in the process of calling Okta API for Authentication "Primary Authentication" as shown in the pic below and I tested this using post man and it was working as expected with proper response.

[image]

I am trying to integrate this API call out with APEX by making use of "Web Source Modules" (APEX version 19.2) as shown below

[image]

There is no Authentication required by this API as it is open. I am unable to discover the service and I am faced with error "405 Method not allowed" when I try to test the POST operation. Thanks to anyone who can help me in this regard.

Comment: is this OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Your web source operations only have put, add post.

Comment: Yes, It only has a put operation, but I figured it out using "UTL_HTTP"

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this, which is to make use of "UTL_HTTP" package in Oracle to get a response and traversing the JSON to get the required data, but making use of "Web Source Modules" would be an easy way as JSON is natively handled by APEX itself internally.